# TypeError: unsupported format string when printing Pandas dataframe with incorrectly shaped index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, printing, traceback

Found this not-so-helpful traceback when incorrectly constructing a data frame with an index.  My question is, is this a bug that I should report to Pandas as an issue or feature request or am I doing something wrong?

What I wanted to do:

```
index = pd.Index(np.array([0, 1]))
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1], 'B': [1.1, 1.2]},
             index=index)
print(df)

   A    B
0  0  1.1
1  1  1.2
```

(works, no problem)

What I actually did (note dimension of index array data):

```
index = pd.Index(np.array([[0], [1]]))
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1], 'B': [1.1, 1.2]},
             index=index)
print(df)
```

Traceback message (very long):

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-95-af090c2ae470> in <module>
      2 df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1], 'B': [1.1, 1.2]},
      3              index=index)
----> 4 print(df)

/anaconda3/envs/torch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __repr__(self)
    653             max_cols=max_cols,
    654             line_width=width,
--> 655             show_dimensions=show_dimensions,
    656         )
    657 

/anaconda3/envs/torch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in to_string(self, buf, columns, col_space, header, index, na_rep, formatters, float_format, sparsify, index_names, justify, max_rows, min_rows, max_cols, show_dimensions, decimal, line_width)
    774             line_width=line_width,
    775         )
--> 776         formatter.to_string()
    777 
    778         if buf is None:

/anaconda3/envs/torch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py in to_string(self)
    686         else:
    687 
--> 688             strcols = self._to_str_columns()
    689             if self.line_width is None:  # no need to wrap around just print
    690                 # the whole frame

/anaconda3/envs/torch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py in _to_str_columns(self)
    586         # may include levels names also
    587 
--> 588         str_index = self._get_formatted_index(frame)
    589 
    590         if not is_list_like(self.header) and not self.header:

/anaconda3/envs/torch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py in _get_formatted_index(self, frame)
    919             )
    920         else:
--> 921             fmt_index = [index.format(name=self.show_row_idx_names, formatter=fmt)]
    922 
    923         fmt_index = [

/anaconda3/envs/torch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in format(self, name, formatter, **kwargs)
   1106             return header + list(self.map(formatter))
   1107 
-> 1108         return self._format_with_header(header, **kwargs)
   1109 
   1110     def _format_with_header(self, header, na_rep="NaN", **kwargs):

/anaconda3/envs/torch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in _format_with_header(self, header, na_rep, **kwargs)
   1130 
   1131         else:
-> 1132             result = _trim_front(format_array(values, None, justify="left"))
   1133         return header + result
   1134 

/anaconda3/envs/torch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py in format_array(values, formatter, float_format, na_rep, digits, space, justify, decimal, leading_space)
   1031     )
   1032 
-> 1033     return fmt_obj.get_result()
   1034 
   1035 

/anaconda3/envs/torch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py in get_result(self)
   1062 
   1063     def get_result(self):
-> 1064         fmt_values = self._format_strings()
   1065         return _make_fixed_width(fmt_values, self.justify)
   1066 

/anaconda3/envs/torch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py in _format_strings(self)
   1293     def _format_strings(self):
   1294         formatter = self.formatter or (lambda x: "{x: d}".format(x=x))
-> 1295         fmt_values = [formatter(x) for x in self.values]
   1296         return fmt_values
   1297 

/anaconda3/envs/torch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py in <listcomp>(.0)
   1293     def _format_strings(self):
   1294         formatter = self.formatter or (lambda x: "{x: d}".format(x=x))
-> 1295         fmt_values = [formatter(x) for x in self.values]
   1296         return fmt_values
   1297 

/anaconda3/envs/torch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py in <lambda>(x)
   1292 class IntArrayFormatter(GenericArrayFormatter):
   1293     def _format_strings(self):
-> 1294         formatter = self.formatter or (lambda x: "{x: d}".format(x=x))
   1295         fmt_values = [formatter(x) for x in self.values]
   1296         return fmt_values

TypeError: unsupported format string passed to numpy.ndarray.__format__
```

Note that the dataframe was constructed (it just can't be printed):

```
In [14]: df.shape                                                             
Out[14]: (2, 2)

In [15]: df.index                                                             
Out[15]: Int64Index([[0], [1]], dtype='int64')

In [16]: df.values                                                            
Out[16]: 
array([[0. , 1.1],
       [1. , 1.2]])

In [18]: df.columns                                                           
Out[18]: Index(['A', 'B'], dtype='object')

In [19]: df.index[0]                                                          
Out[19]: array([0])

In [20]: df.index.dtype                                                       
Out[20]: dtype('int64')
```

Also note that if you make the same mistake with the data arguments...

```
index = pd.Index(np.array([0, 1]))
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.array([[0], [1]]), 'B': np.array([[1.1], [1.2]])},
                  index=index)
print(df)
```

...you get a nice, informative error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-96-218c77e99705> in <module>
      1 index = pd.Index(np.array([0, 1]))
      2 df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.array([[0], [1]]), 'B': np.array([[1.1], [1.2]])},
----> 3                   index=index)
      4 print(df)

/anaconda3/envs/torch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    409             )
    410         elif isinstance(data, dict):
--> 411             mgr = init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
    412         elif isinstance(data, ma.MaskedArray):
    413             import numpy.ma.mrecords as mrecords

/anaconda3/envs/torch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py in init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype)
    255             arr if not is_datetime64tz_dtype(arr) else arr.copy() for arr in arrays
    256         ]
--> 257     return arrays_to_mgr(arrays, data_names, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
    258 
    259 

/anaconda3/envs/torch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py in arrays_to_mgr(arrays, arr_names, index, columns, dtype)
     80 
     81     # don't force copy because getting jammed in an ndarray anyway
---> 82     arrays = _homogenize(arrays, index, dtype)
     83 
     84     # from BlockManager perspective

/anaconda3/envs/torch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py in _homogenize(data, index, dtype)
    321                 val = lib.fast_multiget(val, oindex.values, default=np.nan)
    322             val = sanitize_array(
--> 323                 val, index, dtype=dtype, copy=False, raise_cast_failure=False
    324             )
    325 

/anaconda3/envs/torch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py in sanitize_array(data, index, dtype, copy, raise_cast_failure)
    727     elif subarr.ndim > 1:
    728         if isinstance(data, np.ndarray):
--> 729             raise Exception("Data must be 1-dimensional")
    730         else:
    731             subarr = com.asarray_tuplesafe(data, dtype=dtype)

Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional
```

Version info (`pd.__version__  , np.__version__`)

- `('0.25.3', '1.17.4')`
- `('0.24.2', '1.16.2')`

(I don't like to raise issues until I'm sure it's something worth considering).

Comment: Just noticed.  This seems to be an [open issue with numpy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5543) and [12491](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/12491).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I raised [this issue on the numpy GitHub](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/12491#issuecomment-582229773) and was advised it is an issue with Pandas.  However, I also checked with the latest version of Pandas (1.0.0) and it seems to have been fixed:

```
>>> index = pd.Index(np.array([[0], [1]]))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-ce554b72776c> in <module>
----> 1 index = pd.Index(np.array([[0], [1]]))

/anaconda3/envs/torch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in __new__(cls, data, dtype, copy, name, tupleize_cols, **kwargs)
    388             # maybe coerce to a sub-class
    389             if is_signed_integer_dtype(data.dtype):
--> 390                 return Int64Index(data, copy=copy, dtype=dtype, name=name)
    391             elif is_unsigned_integer_dtype(data.dtype):
    392                 return UInt64Index(data, copy=copy, dtype=dtype, name=name)

/anaconda3/envs/torch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/numeric.py in __new__(cls, data, dtype, copy, name)
     76         if subarr.ndim > 1:
     77             # GH#13601, GH#20285, GH#27125
---> 78             raise ValueError("Index data must be 1-dimensional")
     79 
     80         name = maybe_extract_name(name, data, cls)

ValueError: Index data must be 1-dimensional
```